# Extensão não executa e não apresenta qual o erro

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extensão

Estou com um problema, estou tentando criar uma extensão para verificar o estado de emissão de CPFs, porém ao clicar no botão "verificar" a extensão não faz nada, mas também não apresenta o erro.

Esse é o manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

```
"name": "CPF",
"description": "Verifica o estado de emissão de um CPF",
"version": "1.0",
```

"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "128.png",
   "default_popup": "index.html"

}
}

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', verificar);

function verificar() {
    let cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value.substring(8, 9);

    if (cpf == "0") alert("Rio Grande do Sul");
    else if (cpf == "1") alert(" Distrito Federal – Goiás – Mato Grosso – Mato Grosso do Sul – Tocantins ");
    else if (cpf == "2") alert("  Pará – Amazonas – Acre – Amapá – Rondônia – Roraima");
    else if (cpf == "3") alert(" Ceará – Maranhão – Piauí");
    else if (cpf == "4") alert(" Pernambuco – Rio Grande do Norte – Paraíba – Alagoas ");
    else if (cpf == "5") alert(" Bahia – Sergipe   ");
    else if (cpf == "6") alert("Minas Gerais ");
    else if (cpf == "7") alert("Rio de Janeiro – Espírito Santo");
    else if (cpf == "8") alert(`São Paulo`);
    else if (cpf == "9") alert("Paraná – Santa Catarina");
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #F0E68C;
}

#cpf{
    background-color: #FFFFF0;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
#btn{
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    text-align:center;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF8C00;
}
h1{
    color: #FFFFF0;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
#box{
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>CPF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Digite o CPF</h1>
        <input id="cpf" type="text">
        <button id="btn">Verificar</button>
        <div id="res">
            <h1>
                
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ja tentaste assim ?
Somente por a funcao dentro de um ficheiro .js e referenciar no HTML
E mais talvez fosse melhor verificar o tamanho do input e por mais alguns detetores de erros pois se a minha input for de 3 chars nao vais poder obter o substring 8-9.

```js
function verificar() {

     
    let cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value.substring(8, 9);

    if (cpf == "0") alert("Rio Grande do Sul");
    else if (cpf == "1") alert(" Distrito Federal – Goiás – Mato Grosso – Mato Grosso do Sul – Tocantins ");
    else if (cpf == "2") alert("  Pará – Amazonas – Acre – Amapá – Rondônia – Roraima");
    else if (cpf == "3") alert(" Ceará – Maranhão – Piauí");
    else if (cpf == "4") alert(" Pernambuco – Rio Grande do Norte – Paraíba – Alagoas ");
    else if (cpf == "5") alert(" Bahia – Sergipe   ");
    else if (cpf == "6") alert("Minas Gerais ");
    else if (cpf == "7") alert("Rio de Janeiro – Espírito Santo");
    else if (cpf == "8") alert(`São Paulo`);
    else if (cpf == "9") alert("Paraná – Santa Catarina");
    else alert("Entrou na funcao mas suas condicoes nao sao verificadas.");
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #F0E68C;
}

#cpf{
    background-color: #FFFFF0;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
#btn{
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    text-align:center;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF8C00;
}
h1{
    color: #FFFFF0;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
#box{
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>CPF</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Digite o CPF</h1>
        <input id="cpf" type="text">
        <button onclick="verificar();" id="btn" >Verificar</button>
        <div id="res">
            <h1>
                
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

[image: Rio grande ??]

Comment: Eles são arquivos diferentes, o JS, o HTML e o CSS. O que esta acontecendo é que se eu abro o index.com como site, ele executa perfeitamente, porem se eu abro ele pelo navegador como extensão, ele não só abre o popup, mas ao clicar no botão não executa nada e nem me retorna qual foi o erro.